# How can I duplicate this PHP code in Ruby?

Tags: php, ruby, lambda, closures

I'm moving some projects to Rails and I would like to duplicate this PHP code:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#106046

so far I have this:

```
def html (tag, id = "", hclass = "")
  hopen = "<#{tag}"
  hclose = "</#{tag}>"
  unless id == ""
    hopen += " id=\"#{id}\""
  end

  unless hclass == ""
    hopen += " class=\"#{hclass}\""
  end

  hopen += ">"

  return lambda  { |data| print hopen,data,hclose}
end
```

I need to create variable variables, like this in:
**PHP**

```
$layout = array('container','header','pmain','lsidebar','rsidebar','footer');

foreach ($layout as $element)
   $$element = html ("div", $element);
```

Here is my **RUBY** prototype

```
layout = [:body, :header, :sidebar, :footer]

##I know this isn't right, but how do I create the dynamic functions like PHP???
layout.each {|x| instance_variable_set "@#{x}", 0 }
```

Also, I need to call the functions, is there anyway to do it without the call method? Its going to be messy if I have to nest the calls.

```
h1 = html(:h1)
mainx =  html(:div )
puts mainx.class
puts mainx.call(h1.call("Blog!"))
```

Answer (score 4):

You're doing a lot here, but here's some help with the transition:

```
$layout = array('container','header','pmain','lsidebar','rsidebar','footer');

foreach ($layout as $element)
  $$element = html ("div", $element);
```

This is an array transformation as far as I can tell, so the equivalent is this:

```
layout = [ @container, @header, @pmain, @lsidebar, @rsidebar, @footer]

layout.collect! do |element|
  # Using the built-in content_tag method instead of
  # the custom reimplementation with curried parameters.
  content_tag("div", element)
end
```

There's no Ruby way to de-reference a variable, as variables in Ruby behave in an entirely different manner. Instance variables persist in the context of the object, whereas variables persist only within a given scope. You can get and set arbitrary instance variables by name, but you generally cannot do the same with local variables. There is no `$$var` equivalent in Ruby aside from `eval { var }` which is really frowned on due to how that evaluates potentially arbitrary code.

I really have a bad feeling as to why you'd need to do this, though. Templates are supposed to be a way around having to wrangle things at this low level.

If you're new to Ruby a good thing to do is read through the documentation on String and Array as they are both jammed full of useful methods. Array also includes the Enumerable module which adds even more.

Comment: I am new to Ruby. Your answer really explains a lot! I know about eval but I avoid that like the plague with PHP. Putting aside the HTML issue, is it possible to take an array of symbols or whatever, and use the array to to both create named "function pointers" and use the element as a parameter in the function. It may not be possible from what I see.

Comment: Ruby, like JavaScript, generally doesn't have function pointers, but references to functions, which is a different sort of thing. The best practice in Ruby is to create a Proc that does what you want when called, or to preserve the symbol of the method you want to call. For instance: `container_html = lambda { ... }` or `container_method = :container` followed by `container_html = some_object.send(container_method)`

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a rails project, there is a lot of helpers that helps you to build html

In fact, there is a helper method called **content_tag** that do the same thing. You can see documentation here: http://apidock.com/rails/v3.1.0/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag

Sample usage

```
content_tag(:tag_i_want, :id => 'my_id', :class => 'my_class') do
   "the content I want inside the tag"
end
```

outputs:

```
<tag_i_want id="my_id" class="my_class">the content I want inside the tag</tag_i_want>
```

The second question is a bit weird. Explain more what do you want to do. 
¿Create @body, @header, @sidebar and @footer variables?¿Thats all?

Comment: Thanks, I guess I tried to reinvent the wheel. I wanted a very compact notation though to do it. Still curious how to do that stuff in Ruby :).

Comment: @Len: [`content_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag) takes lots of options but you don't have to supply them all. It can be as compact as this: `content_tag :h1, "Blog!"`. However, your code was pretty close, so clearly you're on the road to understanding. Here's an (oldish) article that might help: http://www.igvita.com/2007/03/15/block-helpers-and-dry-views-in-rails/

Comment: Yes, I wanted to use an array to create those variables which are function pointers. Also, I wanted to use those literals as parameters for the functions. I'm going to do more research from what I'm learning here...thanks!